# tools for traffic shaping

Tags: linux, ip, delay, traffic, trafficshaping

I have to carry out a test where I differentiate (delay or partially drop) some of my outgoing traffic based on a combination of destination port and IP address.

I was thinking of doing it locally on the linux machine where I do my tests.

What are some tools for this? How flexible are they?

Comment: How about iptables? Afaik, you can program them quite comfortably.

Comment: Yes, but in the end I used Dummynet. info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/